# How do I create a tableview with multiple rows and multiple columns?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

I know how to create a tableview with a single column and multiple rows, but I don't know how to create a  tableview with multiple rows and multiple columns.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You should create your custom tableviewcell if you need it look like more than one column

Comment: @Buron would you please suggest any tutorial regarding my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    // load cell from nib to controller's IBOutlet
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCellView" owner:self options:nil];
    // assign IBOutlet to cell
    cell = myCell;
    self.myCell = nil;
  }

  id modelObject = [myModel objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];

  UILabel *label;
  label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
  label.text = [modelObject firstField];

  label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
  label.text = [modelObject secondField];

  label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
  label.text = [modelObject thirdField];

  return cell;
}
```

i think this code will help you UITableView isn't really designed for multiple columns. But you can simulate columns by creating a custom UITableCell class. Build your custom cell in Interface Builder, adding elements for each column. Give each element a tag so you can reference it in your controller.

Give your controller an outlet to load the cell from your nib:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITableViewCell *myCell;
```

Then, in your table view delegate's cellForRowAtIndexPath method, assign those values by tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is how i did it:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

  @interface MyTableCell : UITableViewCell 

{   
NSMutableArray *columns;
 }

- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "MyTableCell.h"

#define LINE_WIDTH 0.25

@implementation MyTableCell

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here.
}

return self;
}

 - (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position 
{
[columns addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:position]];
 }

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// Use the same color and width as the default cell separator for now
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, LINE_WIDTH);

for (int i = 0; i < [columns count]; i++)
{
    CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height);
}

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

[super drawRect:rect];
}

@end
```

and the last piece, cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[rankingTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
cell              = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
```